# Python: dynamic json with string interpolation

Tags: python, json, design-patterns, string-interpolation

I created a class of functions that provision some cloud infrastructure.

```
response = self.ecs_client.register_task_definition(
containerDefinitions=[
                {
                    "name": "redis-283C462837EF23AA",
                    "image": "redis:3.2.7",
                    "cpu": 1,
                    "memory": 512,
                    "essential": True,
                },
...
```

This is a very long json, I show just the beginning.

Then I refactored the code to use a parameter instead of the hard coded hash, memory and cpu.

```
response = self.ecs_client.register_task_definition(
containerDefinitions=[
                {
                    "name": f"redis-{git_hash}",
                    "image": "redis:3.2.7",
                    "cpu": {num_cpu},
                    "memory": {memory_size},
                    "essential": True,
                },
...
```

I read the values of `git_hash`, `num_cpu` and `memory_size` from a config file prior to this code.

Now, I also want to read to entire json from a file.

The problem is that if I save `{num_cpu}` etc. in a file, the string interpolation won't work.

How can I extract the json from my logic and still use string interpolation or variables?

Comment: Why not put everything (the whole JSON) in a simple file? Why do you need to separate a couple of configuration options into a different config file?

Comment: @AlexandruStoica because the json is static, and some variables are dynamic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Template` from `string`.

```
{
    "name": "redis-${git_hash}",
    "image": "redis:3.2.7",
    "cpu": ${num_cpu},
    "memory": ${memory_size},
    "essential": true
}
```

```py
from string import Template
import json

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = dict(
        num_cpu = 1, 
        memory_size = 1,
        git_hash = 1
    )
    with open('test.json', 'r') as json_file:
        content = ''.join(json_file.readlines())
        template = Template(content)
        configuration = json.loads(template.substitute(data))
        print(configuration)

# {'name': 'redis-1', 'image': 'redis:3.2.7', 'cpu': 1, 'memory': 1, 'essential': True}
```

Opinion: I think the overall approach is wrong. There is a reason why this method is not as popular as others. You can separate your configuration into two files (1) a static list of options and (2) your compact changeable configuration, and compose them in your code.

**EDIT**: You can create an object which reads the configuration from a standard (static or changeable) JSON file `FileConfig`. And then compose them using another object, something line `ComposedConfig`.

This will allow you to extend the behaviour, and add, for example, a run-time configuration in the mix. This way the configuration from your JSON file no longer depends on the run-time params, and you can separate what is changeable from what is static in your system.

PS: The `get` method is just an example for explaining the composed behaviour; you can use other methods/designs.

```py
import json
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod 


class Configuration(ABC):
    
    @abstractmethod
    def get(self, key: str, default: str) -> str:
        pass


class FileConfig(Configuration):

    def __init__(self, file_path):
        self.__content = {}
        with open(file_path, 'r') as json_file:
            self.__content = json.load(json_file)
            
    def get(self, key: str, default: str) -> str:
        return self.__content.get(key, default)


class RunTimeConfig(Configuration):
    def __init__(self, option: str):
        self.__content = {'option': option}
    
    def get(self, key: str, default: str) -> str:
        return self.__content.get(key, default)


class ComposedConfig:

    def __init__(self, first: Configuration, second: Configuration):
        self.__first = first
        self.__second = second

    def get(self, key: str, default: str) -> str:
        return self.__first.get(key, self.__second.get(key, default))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    static = FileConfig("static.json")
    changeable = FileConfig("changeable.json")
    runTime = RunTimeConfig(option="a")
    config = ComposedConfig(static, changeable)
    alternative = ComposedConfig(static, runTime)
    print(config.get("image", "test")) # redis:3.2.7
    print(alternative.get("option", "test")) # a
```

Comment: If it try to save that json in a file, I'm getting an error from PyCharm: JSON standard does not allow such tokens

Comment: Could you write an example of separate files, as you suggested in the end?

Comment: PyCharm just checks the structure of your JSON file, and because this is not formatted correctly, it will complain, but you will be able to run your Python application with no problem. You can also save the JSON content as a `.txt` file to ignore the issue.

Comment: Eventually I went on the first solution with the Template class. It's perfect. I solved the errors by storing {num_cpu} etc. like that: "${num_cpu}". Mulțumesc!